# Android ANR: The "main" (tid=1) thread is in suspended state. This is likely due to garbage collection

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I am wondering if there is anything that an app can do to avoid the following Android ANR (from Goolge Play Console):

> The "main" (tid=1) thread is in suspended state. This is likely due to
>   garbage collection.

```
"main" tid=1 Suspended Thread suspended
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ca59a0 self=0x41a46010
  | sysTid=11845 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074713820
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=64 stm=22 core=1
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal (LinearLayout.java)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:590)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal (LinearLayout.java:1052)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:590)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:681)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:4825)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:2176)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:15520)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1282)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:4369)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:749)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:562)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:532)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:735)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:725)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5041)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:818)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:584)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution..?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad No, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this? If it's something happening because your app tries to resume after being garbage collected, you might want to finish your app manually in onTrimMemory() and avoid resuming it with insufficient resources.

Comment: @ANemati  No, unfortunately.   I  receive this kind of ANR reports from Google Play occasionally.

Comment: @Hong, I am also receiving this kind of ANR reports from Google Play